# existence of real-valued smooth function with certain properties

Tags: real-analysis

Let $L$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$.
I am trying to find a a smooth function $\varphi\colon \mathbb{C}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that has the following properties:

1) $\varphi \geq 0$

2) $supp(\varphi)$ is compact

3) the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C}^{n}\mid \varphi(z)>0\}$ includes a fundamental parallelepiped of $L$

As of right now I struggle coming up with any ideas, so maybe you can enlighten me a little.

Comment: Is a lattice in $\mathbb C ^n$ the same as a lattice in $\mathbb R ^{2n}?$

Comment: Yes exactly that

Answer (score 0):

The function $g(t) = \exp [-1/(t+1)(2-t)], -1<t<2,g(t) = 0$ elsewhere, is smooth on $\mathbb {R},$ positive on $[0,1],$ and has compact support. If we define

$$f(x) = g(x_1)g(x_2)\cdots g(x_{2n}), x \in \mathbb {R}^{2n},$$

then $f$ is smooth on $\mathbb {R}^{2n},$ is positive on $C=[0,1]^{2n},$ and has compact support. The cube $C$ is of course a fundamental parallelopiped relative to the lattice $\mathbb {Z}^{2n}.$

Let $L$ be the lattice determined by the basis $v_1,\dots ,v_{2n}$ of $\mathbb {R}^{2n}.$ Then there is a unique linear transformation $T:\mathbb {R}^{2n} \to \mathbb {R}^{2n}$ such that $T(v_j) = e_j,$ where $e_1,\dots,e_{2n}$ is the standard basis. $T$ maps a fundamental parallelopiped of $L$ onto $C.$ You can check that $f\circ T$ has the desired properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! (I didn't check it yet as I just read it)